# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_strpos()

Tags: php, joomla, fatal-error, mbstring

I got stuck into this problem and I can't seem to find a solution.

The version of PHP installed in the server is 5.3.22. After installing Joomla and the default sample data I got this error accessing the web site:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_strpos() in /public_html/site/templates/yoo_sync/layouts/module.php on line 115
```

I checked the phpinfo page and I noticed that option `--enable-mbstring` is missing:

[image: before adding the handler]

I spoke with the hosting company's support team and they told me to add the following entry to the .htaccess file in the Joomla installation directory:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php55 .php
```

Now I can see the option there but many of the others are missing:

[image: after adding the handler]

which causes the following error (due to the missing options):

```
Database connection error (1): The MySQL adapter 'mysqli' is not available.
```

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: the library is already installed in the system but not enabled by default.

Comment: So enabling it solves your problem?

Comment: how do I do that? I added the handler to .htaccess as specified in the post and got it enabled but got more errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was fixed by adding `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php55 .php` to the `.htaccess` at the root level (~/public_html)

Answer (score 4):

On windows installations (and maybe others as well), php_mbstring.dll is not loaded by default. Uncomment it in php.ini
That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 3):

Just switch the code to JString:strpos().
Joomla does not require that you have mb installed.